# openam13 snapshot ssoadm setup exception: ClassNotFoundException: org.forgerock.services.TransactionId

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, opensso

I am getting the following exception while trying to run the ssoadm .setup script. This is with openam13 snapshot version i got on 01/04/2016. It worked before that. Can anyone point me to what might be the issue?

```
 Executing command "/Users/sso-config/target/ssoadmintools/setup --path /apps/openam/server --log /apps/openam/log --acceptLicense --debug /apps/openam/debug" in working directory target/ssoadmintools/
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/forgerock/services/TransactionId
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditRequestContext$1.initialValue(AuditRequestContext.java:35)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditRequestContext$1.initialValue(AuditRequestContext.java:32)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditRequestContext.get(AuditRequestContext.java:124)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditRequestContext.createSubTransactionIdValue(AuditRequestContext.java:160)
        at org.forgerock.openam.ldap.LDAPRequests.newSimpleBindRequest(LDAPRequests.java:54)
        at org.forgerock.openam.ldap.LDAPUtils.newConnectionFactory(LDAPUtils.java:249)
        at org.forgerock.openam.ldap.LDAPUtils.newFailoverConnectionFactory(LDAPUtils.java:200)
        at com.iplanet.services.ldap.DSConfigMgr.getNewFailoverConnectionFactory(DSConfigMgr.java:324)
        at com.iplanet.services.ldap.DSConfigMgr.getNewConnectionFactory(DSConfigMgr.java:289)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.Bootstrap.getConfiguration(Bootstrap.java:190)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:136)
        at com.sun.identity.tools.bundles.Main.main(Main.java:143)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.forgerock.services.TransactionId
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 14 more
    Command process exited with value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the setup command from the directory where the script is located instead of using the absolute path to the script?

Try this:

```
./setup --path /apps/openam/server --log /apps/openam/log --acceptLicense --debug /apps/openam/debug
```

Instead of this:

```
/Users/sso-config/target/ssoadmintools/setup --path /apps/openam/server --log /apps/openam/log --acceptLicense --debug /apps/openam/debug
```

My guess is that java cannot find some libraries in the classpath when you use the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck even with running the setup command from the directory where the script is located.

Comment: This looks to me like there was an issue with the openam13 snapshot version i got on 01/04/2016. It works fine with the snapshot versions prior to that and after that. I'll check if there are any classpath issues or missing jars in the 01/04 version